# Additional listener name creation for same AG fails using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-clustering

I am creating a AG listener in Windows Cluster using powershell srcipts.

Add-ClusterResource doesn't create ADAware resource. I hope I am not using the correct account to create the resource.  You can see the Name not configure and DNS name of the resource is missing the cluster properties.

[Listener properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDm9R.png)
[Error while trying to add Listener name in DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyb1H.png)

I tested the listener creation manually it works fine. Cluster service has permissions to create Computer objects. It work manually fine.

Using below powershell script

```
    $listenerResource = $AvailabilityGroup + "_Listener_" + $newAGListenerSuffix
    Add-ClusterResource -Cluster $cluster -Name $listenerResource -Group $AvailabilityGroup -   ResourceType 'Network Name'
    Write-Verbose "Additional Availability group listener name - $listenerResource has been created"

    $ec2Instance = ''
    $instanceId = ''
    $IP = ''
    $subnetMask = ''
    $networkInterface = Get-ClusterNetworkInterface -Cluster $cluster -Node $node
    $IPDetails = @{
    Network=$networkInterface.Network
    Address=$IP
    SubnetMask=$subnetMask
    EnableDhcp=0
    }

    $ipResourceName = $listenerResource + '_' + $IP
    #Add Cluster resource type IP Address for Listener.
    $IPAddressResource = (Add-ClusterResource -Cluster $cluster -Name $ipResourceName -Group $AvailabilityGroup -ResourceType 'IP Address')
    #Pass IP address properties of the listener in $IPDetails
    Get-ClusterResource -Cluster $cluster -Name $IPAddressResource.Name | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple $IPDetails
    Write-Verbose "New listener IP Address $IPAddressResource has been created for $node."
    #Create dependency on the IP address for Listener Name. By default the dependency on ip's is created using 'AND' (ie on all ip's)
    Add-ClusterResourceDependency -Cluster $cluster -Resource $listenerResource -Provider $ipResourceName

    #I get error in the below section because the listener resource is not online. 

    **    #Listener requirement is the have dependency on one of the IP's. Hence resetting the dependency with 'or'.
    $listenerDependency = (Get-ClusterResourceDependency -Cluster $cluster -Resource $listenerResource)
    Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource $listenerResource -Dependency $listenerDependency.DependencyExpression.Replace('and','or')
    Write-Verbose "New listener IP Address $IPAddressResource dependency has been created for $node."**

    Write-Verbose "Stopping $AvailabilityGroup"
    Stop-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster -Name $AvailabilityGroup
    <#Create AG dependency on the Listener. By default dependency is created on all listeners with 'and'. #>
    Add-ClusterResourceDependency -Cluster $cluster -Resource $AvailabilityGroup -Provider $listenerResource

    #Set AG dependencies to be dependent on any one online listener resource.
    $AGDependency = (Get-ClusterResourceDependency -Cluster $cluster -Resource $listenerResource)
    Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource $AvailabilityGroup -Dependency $AGDependency.DependencyExpression.Replace('and','or')
    Write-Verbose "Availability group $AvailabilityGroup dependency on listener $listenerResource has been created"

    #Set HostRecordTimeToLive. To let Clients refresh the DNS cache of the Cluster details.
    #Set RegisterAllProvidersIP to '0', To let the clients connect only to Primary IP address.****
    $cluster | Get-Clusterresource -Name $listenerResource | Set-ClusterParameter -Name HostRecordTTL -Value $HostRecordTimeToLive
    $cluster | Get-ClusterResource -Name $listenerResource | Set-ClusterParameter RegisterAllProvidersIP 0
    Write-Verbose "HostRecordTimeToLive set to $HostRecordTimeToLive, RegisterAllProvidersIP set to 0"

    Write-Verbose "Starting $AvailabilityGroup"
    Start-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster -Name $AvailabilityGroup
```

Comment: After adding the cluster parameter to Set-ClusterresourceDependency. I was able to move forward a bit. 
 Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Cluster $cluster -Resource $listenerResource -Dependency $listenerDependency.DependencyExpression.Replace('and','or')
    

But the Cluster didn't start because the DNS name of the role is not registered.